# Can't use wxWidgets: wxmsw31ud_core.pdb(0,0): Error LNK1136 fatal: invalid or corrupt file

Tags: windows, build, visual-studio-2017, wxwidgets, static-linking

I followed the [Creating a new project by hand](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide#Creating_a_new_project_by_hand) after building the `wx_vc15.sln` solution in the `...\wxWidgets\build\msw` dir.

I get this error:

`...\wxWidgets\lib\vc_x64_lib\wxmsw31ud_core.pdb(0,0): Error LNK1136 fatal: invalid or corrupt file`

After rechecking everything (unicode, static linking, `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)`, ...), I couldn't find the reason for the error.

These are the preprocessor's definitions I added to the wxWidgets solution, as explained in the [Creating a new project by hand](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide#Creating_a_new_project_by_hand) page:

```
WIN32
_LIB
_DEBUG
_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1
_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1
_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1
__WXMSW__
WXBUILDING
wxUSE_BASE=0
```

(The `_UNICODE` is inherited, no need to add it I presume).

Comment: VS uses to change things from one version to another. I mean, the wiki may be outdated for VS15. I advise this route: Open the project for a sample (start with "minimal"); study the different flags/defines/libs/whatever for each target (debug, release, 32 or 64 bits, etc); Copy them for your own project.

Comment: Are you trying to link a .pdb file?  Maybe you accidentally chose the .pdb instead of the .lib as a link dependency?

Comment: Also to link dll files on VS, WXUSINGDLL is needed.

Comment: @avariant,  how embarrassing... accidentally copied/pasted one of the `pdb`s file instead of its `lib`.